# Looking for a serial 9800 baud device that can input a string and output a modified string

Tags: serial, rs232

I'm looking for a simple programmable device that has RS232 inputs and outputs that can take a string of ten numbers and output a modified string over <strike>9800</strike> 9600  baud, 8 bits, 1 stop bit, parity: none.

For example:

input:

`0123456789`

output:

`the+string+is+now+1234567890`

I know I could do it with something like an Arduino but I am looking for something a little simpler and hopefully more reliable.

Comment: You could possibly implement this with the USI on a ATtinyX5, but I wouldn't want to.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated how much computing is needed to transform the input to the output, but I'd use a simple, self-contained, 8-bit microcontroller, such as the Silican Labs [C8051F305](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F305-short.pdf). Something like this will require very few external components, though you will need a logic-level-to-RS232 converter chip and a  few misc. components, such as decoupling caps.

The micro above has 2KB of flash, 128 bytes of RAM, UART and does not require an external oscillator/crystal. It costs around US$2.00 in single quantities.

Comment: 8051? Really???

Comment: Believe it or not, there are a lot of 8-bit microcontrollers built around 8051 cores. However, they have enhanced instruction sets and run reasonable fast; the one I suggested runs with a 20MHz clock speed. For a simple application, transforming data on a serial port, especially at only 9600 bps, it is plenty.

Comment: I know there are a lot of them out there. However, I don't think they're a good idea for *new* projects, particularly for beginners. Unless you have a lot of legacy code, there are many much newer, nicer architecture, better documented MCUs out there.

Comment: You could bit bang that in the 6 pin PICs or take the easy route and use the smallest with a hardware UART...